# Converting a Scala Iterable[T] to an Option[Iterable[S]], populated if ALL the T are instances of S?

Tags: scala, casting, scala-collections, scala-cats

I have a vague feeling that such a method could exist (possibly in [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/)?) - the purpose would be to turn an `Iterable[T]` (*or `Set[T]` is what I'm actually interested in*) into an `Option[Iterable[S]]` - the result being:

- `Some[Iterable[S]]` : if **all** entries in the `Iterable[T]` were an instance of `S`
- `None` : if any entries in the `Iterable[T]` were NOT an instance of `S`

I know there's a sort-of-similar method already available in Cats, granted by [`Alternative`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/alternative.html) - it's `separate`:

```
import cats.implicits._
import alleycats.std.set._

val stringsAndInts: Set[Either[String, Int]] = Set(Right(6),Left("Foo"))
val (strings: Set[String], ints: Set[Int]) = stringsAndInts.separate
```

...that works nicely for a `Set[Either[A,B]` - but for this question I'm just interested in any old `Set[T]`.

##### What about `collect`?

This code using the Scala standard library method [`collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/Iterable.html#collect%5BB%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5BA,B%5D):CC%5BB%5D) will compile - but note that it will always produce a `Set[S]` - even if some of the `setOfT` weren't instances of `S`:

```
val setOfT: Set[T] = ???
val setOfS: Set[S] = setOfT.collect {case s: S => s}
```

Comment: If you have arbitrary types this can not work out of the box due to type-erasure. You either need to write a specific method for some subset of types or create your own **typeclass** to validate the data. - Or you can use runtime reflection and open the door to bugs due type erasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider shapeless type safe cast

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.typeable._

val xs: Set[Any] = Set("picard", "worf")

xs.cast[Set[Int]]
// res1: Option[Set[Int]] = None

xs.cast[Set[String]]
// res2: Option[Set[String]] = Some(value = Set("picard", "worf"))
```

---

If you wish similar power to `collect` and already have cats on classpath then here is one-liner

```
import alleycats.std.set._
animals.map(implicitly[ClassTag[Dog]].unapply).sequence
```

which types to `Option[Set[Dog]]`.

Comment: Hello Mario! Brilliant stuff - so this is using a Scala macro to get around type-erasure, is that right? https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeable.scala

Comment: @RobertoTyley Yes, and unlike [ClassTag#unapply](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8a2cf63ee5bad8c8c054f76464de0e10226516a0/src/library/scala/reflect/ClassTag.scala#L76) it also works with parameterised types. [docs](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#type-safe-cast)

Answer (score 1):

As Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez points out in his comment, a method like the one I want isn't possible for arbitrary types, due to type-erasure.

In the end, I wrote code like this:

```scala
val animals: Set[Animal] = ???
val optDogs: Option[Set[Dog]] = animals.foldLeft(Option(Set.empty[Dog])) {
  case (oDogs, dog: Dog) => oDogs.map(_ + dog)
  case _ => None
}
```

...would be happy to see better implementations though!

Comment: You can just do `aminals.collect { case dog: Dog => dog }` and check if it is non empty. You can also do `animals.traverse { case dog: Dog => Some(dog); case _ => None }` or you can generalize it using your own **Typeclass**  something `trait Is[T, U] { def check(t: T): Option[U] }` which in the end would do the same `match` and can be used with the same `traverse` but it seems **Shapeless* already solved it for you :)